# Appropriate response for how long you have been working?

Tags: terminology

I am working on an application for permanent residency in another country and the question of how long I have been at my current job came up. The form only has a pulldown menu to pick between and there is no other option to enter an alternate response. The question is "How long have you been employed at your current job" and the answers that possibly apply to me are "1-2 years," and "3+" years." I have been at my job for 2 years and a few months, which doesn't seem to fit into either of those two choices.

When it comes to indicating how long you've been with a company, how do you address rounding the years like this? Since I have been here for more than 2 years do I immediately go up to the next tier? Or since I have not been here for a FULL 3 years, do I not yet qualify for the 3+ years?

I realize this might not be exactly workplace-related but there might be an understood answer that is relevant to places of employment, rather than if this were a general math question or something else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an application for permanent residency, not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: This might be more appropriate over at [expats.se].

Comment: If those are the only choices, I would guess that "1-2 years" should be interpreted as "more than 1 year but less than 3", so that's what I would pick.

Answer (score 6):

The appropriate response is to look for instructions to fill the form, and when not available, to ask the people who gave you the form. This also applies to every other scenario where how to fill a form is not clear.

Comment: It's an online form and there are no people to contact in this case. However, I will repost in a different sub.

Comment: @Alister I am willing to bet there definitely are people to contact in this case, and you will find them if you look for the info. If it is an application for residency in another country, you can surely find a helpdesk or whatever to answer such queries. If not, then whoever asked you to fill this online form should be able to tell whom to ask.

Comment: welcome back MM